# How to change background colour in kasper theme?

Tags: css, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

There's a theme `https://github.com/rosario/kasper`.

[image: screenshot]

How can i change the colour **#D6EDFF** to something else? I can't change the colour even after editing the css file. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the css file of this theme compiles from sass. Go to  `kasper/_sass/_syntax.scss`, there you can find and edit all the colors used in the theme. Then trigger a jekyll build. Good luck.